# Count Numbers of 0 and 1 in an array

Tags: java, arrays

How can I count numbers of 0, 1, 2 in an array.
 I have an array `int [] A= {0,0,0,0,1,1,2,2,2}`, how could I count numbers of 0, 1 and 2 in it using java.

I just know the code below which is used to count elements in array:

down vote
Iterate through it and count the elements which aren't null:

```
    int counter = 0;
     for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i ++)
         if (A[i] != null)
         counter ++;
```

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
     int  idx [] = { 1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,2};

     int[] count_x1 =new int[X]; //x==3. for example 
            for (int j : idx){
                   count_x1[j]++;
                      }
```

I update the code still have  an error :(

Comment: First time I've seen a question ask for a downvote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you only continues values(0,1,2,3....)

```
int[] A = {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2}; // any number and values will work!

int max = IntStream.of(A).max().getAsInt(); // gets max value in array
int[] counter = new int[max + 1]; 
for (int i = 0; i < A.length; ++i)
    counter[A[i]]++;
```

Comment: i am receiving error which is for each is not applicable for expression type, i just use 3 as an example in my real array it is increase

Comment: @  hello_world   perfect  :)

Comment: @MrmemAziz do upvote and accept as answer! Glad i could help :)

Comment: upvote is probably not possible for you at your current reputation stats. just select as answer! thanks!

Answer (score 1):

int [] A= {0,0,0,0,1,1,2,2,2} is an array, you could use a collection and call the method `Collections.frequency`

## Example:

```
int[] A = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2 };
List<Integer> l = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i : A) {
    l.add(i);
}
System.out.println(Collections.frequency(l, 0));
System.out.println(Collections.frequency(l, 1));
System.out.println(Collections.frequency(l, 2));
```

Comment: i just use 3 as  an example  , 0, 1, 2 it is not constant  , if it is increses  to 0, 1, 2, 3 .... etc how can we do that ?

Answer (score 0):

First you need a helper array of size 3 to keep track of how many times each of the digits 0,1,2 appear in the input array.

Then you iterate over the input array and increment the helper array cell corresponding to the digit you encounter by 1.

See code below

```
Integer[] numToSearch = { 0,1,2 };
Integer[] helper = new Integer[3];
for (int i=0;i<3;i++)
    helper[i] = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i ++)
     if (A[i] == numToSearch[0])
         helper[0]++;
     if (A[i] == numToSearch[1])
         helper[1]++
     if (A[i] == numToSearch[2])
         helper[2]++;
for (int i=0;i<helper.length;i++)
     System.out.println("Number of " + numToSearch[i] + "s in array: "+helper[i]);
```

Comment: i just use 3 as an example , 0, 1, 2 it is not constant , if it is increses to 0, 1, 2, 3 .... etc how can we do that ? – Mrmem Aziz just now   edit

Comment: Seriously? I just gave you the entire answer to your HW, please do the minimum, no one here is working for you.

Comment: Iam sorry if i am bothering you but  your code has limitation which is ( 0,1,2) and if  it change to 0,1,2,3 ...etc i should change the entire code :(

Comment: No, it does not have that limitation at all

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you trying to change here? The if statement or the entire code block? I personally would use a switch/case to replace the if checks as long as you know that your array is only 0's, 1's, and 2's. If you also know your array is in order you could just count the number of elements in the array until the element changes.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is counting arbitrary values in an array of ints, you can use this:

```java
Map<Integer, Integer> counter = new HashMap<>();

int [] A= {0,0,0,0,1,1,2,2,2};

for (int i : A) {
  Integer currentCount = counter.get(i);
  counter.put(i, (currentCount == null) ? 1 : currentCount + 1);
}

for (Integer i : counter.keySet())
   System.out.println(i + ": " + counter.get(i));
```